# How to nicely unpack unordered_map element in range-based for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop

Consider this code:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>    
int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int,std::string> map {{5,"five"},{1,"one"},{-7,"minus seven"}};
    int x;
    std::string s;
    for(std::tie(x,s) : map)
        std::cout << x << "->" << s << "\n";
}
```

Here on the line with `for` I get the an error from clang++-3.6:

> test.cpp:14:23: error: for range declaration must declare a variable

This seems to mean I'm out of luck with `std::tie` to unpack the `pair` which `val` would be if I did `for(auto val: map)`.

But I'd really like to automatically unpack the pair without any extra line in the loop body. Is there still any elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Since you're so worried about a bit of extra code, I'll mention that your map creation is very verbose. It could be `std::unordered_map<int,std::string> map{{5, "five"}, {1, "one"}, {-7, "minus seven"}};`

Comment: @chris thanks, didn't think about this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ val will be `std::pair<int, std::string>`.

Comment: @ForEveR Yup, you're right.

Comment: Do you want to display the contents in a sorted manner?

Comment: I'd really just put the `tie` call in the body, but it should be possible to create something that works like `for (auto dummy : map | unpack_to(x,s))`

Comment: Just don't call a map a map. Next time someone does #include <map> and "using namespace std;" your map will become a re-definition of std::map container.

Comment: @V-R isn't it the exact reason why `using namespace std;` is considered bad practice?

Comment: It is considered bad practice to put it in a header; in the scope of a function body it would be perfectly fine. I routinely put it in my CPP files after all the includes, so I don't have to repeat it in every function scope. I don't think it's even considered bad practice that way. But if you like the freedom of using names like "map" for your own code, consider wrapping your code in a namespace. But of course that would be an overkill for a small example code and of course this is all totally beside the point of the post. Sorry for digressing.

Comment: @V-R typename should not conflict with variable name, I do not think there will be conflict there.

Comment: @V-R Names at function scope hide names at namespace scope so this is a non-issue. You do not have to treat all names in `std` as if they were reserved. http://ideone.com/hIX9yO

Comment: @Oktalist, you are right, unless the "own" map would be a type. And even then with proper use of namespaces, the names in std don't generally need to be treated as reserved, although in my large unrefactored codebase at work it makes perfect sense to treat these things and much more as reserved. Sorry, I was imprecise, biased and digressed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These days the best way to do it is using [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) that appeared in C++17, like in the code below.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>    
int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int,std::string> map {{5,"five"},{1,"one"},{-7,"minus seven"}};
    for(const auto& [x,s] : map)
        std::cout << x << " -> " << s << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of ideas. The first one requires an extra line of preample to construct a pair of iterators, and uses a `while` loop:

```
template <typename I, typename... Ts>
bool for_tie(std::pair<I,I>& its, Ts&&... parts)
{
    if (its.first == its.second) return false;
    std::tie(std::forward<Ts>(parts)...) = *its.first++;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int,std::string> map {{5,"five"},{1,"one"},{-7,"minus seven"}};
    int x;
    std::string s;
    auto map_its = std::make_pair(begin(map), end(map));
    while(for_tie(map_its, x, s))
        std::cout << x << "->" << s << "\n";
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61b8af7d915ff54c)

The next one has an API similar to the standard library algorithms, used here with a lambda:

```
#include <experimental/tuple>

template <typename I, typename F>
void for_tie(I it, I end, F func)
{
    for (; it != end; ++it) std::experimental::apply(func, *it);
}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int,std::string> map {{5,"five"},{1,"one"},{-7,"minus seven"}};
    for_tie(begin(map), end(map), [](int x, const std::string &s) {
        std::cout << x << "->" << s << "\n";
    });
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31e4bc1dce548208)

[`std::experimental::apply`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/apply) is easy to implement yourself if you don't have access to an implementation of the library fundamentals TS.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the idea, to use special template class  `map_unpacker`, it not suppose to be completed in any sense, just to show the idea:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <tuple>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct map_unpacker {
    typedef typename std::unordered_map<T1,T2> convert_map;
    typedef typename convert_map::const_iterator convert_iterator;
    typedef typename convert_map::value_type pair;

    struct iterator : convert_iterator {
        iterator( const map_unpacker &u, convert_iterator it ) : unpack( u ), convert_iterator( it ) {}

        pair operator*() { auto &&p = convert_iterator::operator*(); unpack.ref1 = p.first; unpack.ref2 = p.second; return p; }

        const map_unpacker &unpack;
    };

    map_unpacker( const std::unordered_map<T1,T2> &m, T1 &r1, T2 &r2 ) : map( m ), ref1( r1 ), ref2( r2 ) {}

    iterator begin() const { return iterator( *this, map.begin() ); }
    iterator end() const { return iterator( *this, map.end() ); }

private:
    const std::unordered_map<T1,T2> &map;
    T1 &ref1;
    T2 &ref2;
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int,std::string> map {{5,"five"},{1,"one"},{-7,"minus seven"}};
    int x;
    std::string s;
    for( auto &&v : map_unpacker<int,std::string>( map, x, s ) ) {
        std::cout << "x==" << x << " s==" << s << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: We had about the same idea ... I like your method of actually putting the stuff into the variables when the iterator is dereferenced. Still, the whole effort just for saving one line is silly.

Comment: @ChrisInked why not? this code can be written once and used many times, then that effort would not be so silly. Though I am not sure I need to unpack  pair in map iteration at all.

Comment: I just don't like these classes very much that exist for the sole purpose of saving an extra line but at the same time introducing overhead and increasing complexity. I prefer simple, readable, no extra-knowledge requiring code.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, since you like the syntax sugar and might not be so concerned about the performance, how about this idea I came up with:

Build your own class which wraps around the map and returns its own iterators, which in turn save the values in x and s every time the iterator gets incremented.

The following code might not be the best I've ever written but it solves your problem, fulfills your constraints and can be further improved by you.

```
class mai_tie
{
public:
    class iterator
    {
    public:
        iterator(std::unordered_map<int, std::string>::iterator& pos, std::unordered_map<int, std::string>::iterator& end, int& x, std::string& s)
        : _pos(pos), _end(end), _x(&x), _s(&s)
        {
            *_x = pos->first;
            *_s = _pos->second;
        }

        iterator(std::unordered_map<int, std::string>::iterator pos) : _pos(pos), _end(pos)
        {}

        bool operator==(const iterator& rhs)
        { return _pos == rhs._pos; }

        bool operator!=(const iterator& rhs)
        { return _pos != rhs._pos; }

        void operator++()
        {
            ++_pos;
            if (_pos != _end && _x && _s)
            { 
                *_x = _pos->first;
                *_s = _pos->second;
            }
        }

        std::pair<int, std::string> operator*()
        {
            return std::make_pair(_pos->first, _pos->second);
        }

    private:
        std::unordered_map<int, std::string>::iterator _pos;
        const std::unordered_map<int, std::string>::iterator _end;
        int* _x = nullptr;
        std::string* _s = nullptr;
    };

    mai_tie(std::unordered_map<int, std::string>& map, int& x, std::string& s) : _map(map), _x(x), _s(s) {};

    iterator begin()
    {
        return iterator(_map.begin(), _map.end(), _x, _s);
    }

    iterator end()
    {
        return iterator(_map.end());
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<int, std::string>& _map;
    int& _x;
    std::string& _s;
};
```

And you will use it like this:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::string> map{ { 5, "five" }, { 1, "one" }, { -7, "minus seven" } };
int x;
std::string s;
for (auto z : mai_tie(map, x, s))
    std::cout << x << "->" << s << "\n";
```

Forgive me the name of this class, I felt "funny" today.

And a personal advice: Do not use this class. Nobody will know what the F is going on in your code. Write regular, simple code. Saving one line is just not worth it. The next coder after you will be thankful (speaking from experience, already debugged a lot of code where people made "clever" things like this to save a few lines).

Answer (score 0):

You can change your for loop as follows:

```
for(const auto& ele: map)
  std::cout<< ele.first<<"->"<<ele.second<<"\n";
```

**EDIT**

```
for(const auto& x : map)
{
    std::tie(y,s)=x;
    std::cout << y << "->" << s << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted to avoid — using `pair` as a `pair`. I'm looking for an elegant way to assign `first` and `second` to some variables.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I'm looking for a way `without any extra line in the loop body`. Your answers seem to hint that there isn't any way, at least sufficiently elegant.